# Storing each sentence in an array from a document in java?

Tags: java, arrays, words, sentence

I want to split every sentence from a document and store each sentence in different arrays. Each array element is 
the word of the sentences. But i cant get far from this.

```
int count =0,len=0;
String sentence[];
String words[][];
sentence = name.split("\\.");
count = sentence.length;

System.out.print("total sentence: " );
System.out.println(count);
int h;  
words = new String[count][]; 

for (h = 0; h < count; h++) {
     String tmp[] = sentence[h].split(" ");
     words[h] = tmp;
     len = len + words[h].length;
     System.out.println("total words: " );
     System.out.print(len); 

     temp = sentence[h].split(delimiter);  

     for(int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(len);
        System.out.println(temp[i]);
        len++;
     }  
}
```

Comment: This code is okay.I don't know how to store word in array. I did split every word from sentence. but how can i store them in array ?

Comment: When you use the `split` method, it gives you an array as a result, no need to make one.

Comment: oh! but how can i see or access the array? i need to use the array for further calculation.

Comment: If you do something like `words[] = someString.split(" ")` then the array `words` contains all the elements that were split around a space. Now you can access those elements like `words[0]`, `words[1]`, etc...

Comment: Is there anything else that isn't working?

Comment: After spliting, for each sentence, how can i store words of the sentence in different arrays where each word is an element of the array. like this -
i eat rice. array[1]={i,eat,rice}
he is a boy. array[2]={he,is,a,boy}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't understand your code, but here's how to achieve your *stated* intention with just 3 lines:

```
String document; // read from somewhere

List<List<String>> words = new ArrayList<>();
for (String sentence : document.split("[.?!]\\s*"))
    words.add(Arrays.asList(sentence.split("[ ,;:]+")));
```

If you want to convert the `Lists` to arrays, use `List.asArray()`, but I wouldn't recommend it. Lists are far easier to deal with than arrays. For one, they expand automatically (one reason why the above code is so dense).

Addendum: (most) characters don't need escaping inside a character class.

Comment: showing this errors-
List cannot be resolved to a type.
List cannot be resolved to a type.
ArrayList cannot be resolved to a type.
Syntax error on token "<", ? expected after this token.
Arrays cannot be resolved.

Comment: @user3503711 you need to `import java.util.*;`. And if you're using java 6, use `new ArrayList<List<String>>()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your input string is stored in `main`.
I do not understand what the inner `for` loop is supposed to do: it prints `len` repeatedly, but does not update it!

```
String sentences[];
String words[][];

// End punctuation marks are ['.', '?', '!']
sentences = name.split("[\\.\\?\\!]"); 

System.out.println("num of sentences: " + sentences.length);

// Allocate stogage for (sentences.length) new arrays of strings
words = new String[sentences.length][];

// For each sentence
for (int h = 0; h < sentences.length; h++) {
  // Remove spaces from beginning and end of sentence (to avoid 0-length words)
  // split by any white space character sequence (caution if using Unicode!)
  words[h] = sentences[h].trim().split("\\s+"); 

  // Print out length of sentence.
  System.out.println("words (in sentence " + (h+1) + "): " + words[h].length);
}
```

Comment: Actually length just to see if the code the working! what i need is>>

**input - i eat rice.he is a boy.
output like -array[1]={i,eat,rice} . array[2]={he,is,a,boy}**